# Desktop Harddrive compatibility

Tags: hard-drive, dell

I just bought a used desktop that does not have a harddrive.  I am going to get a replacement but was not sure which harddrives brand or model works well with linux and urbuntu.  Any recommendations.  The Desktop is a Dell and has a SATA connection.

Answer (score 3):

Any SATA hard drive should do just fine. Even laptop SATA hard drives are compatible with desktop PCs.

One thing you need to make sure is that if you have a SATA III compatible motherboard, don't waste your money on SATA II hard drives. Same principle goes for SATA II and SATA I.

Answer (score 1):

So the desktops use 3.5" format,
Spindle speed and buffer size are important, i recommend 7200 (or more, but those get costly)
Also look at how much size you want, over 150GB is good to start, some can make do with less, but for storing music and movies the more the merrier. So I would recommend a good 300-500 GB drive. I like Seagate for drives, they have a great warranty program, where you can check warranty status ( http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/warranty_%26_returns_assistance ) and they let you ship back the drive for a replacement (if faulty) directly. They drives are the ones that have parallel bit technology, so the cost is less when you compare sizes directly with the competitors.

This is a nice one
http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=744346&CatId=2459

this is a bit more conservative, less cost
http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=143901&CatId=2457